# Run site using specific web.config transformation in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using the web.config transformations on an ASP.NET site so I have .config settings for dev, test, and release environments. I need to run the source code in Visual Studio against the test database using the settings in Web.Test.config and I can't figure out how to do it. I tried changing the configuration to Test but it still uses the base Web.config settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to modify the local web.config file to be able to do this.  When running the project via the VS web server no transformations are completed.  They are only done on publish.